# How to check if device is offline in AWS IoT Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

What is the best practice to check if AWS IoT Core thing is still offline?

Being able to query the state of an AWS IoT thing will for many be an essential part of their application. Lucky AWS has a best practise on how to get lifecycle events here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

In the documentation there is a section describing how to deal with lifecycle events an here they mention that after receiving a disconnect life cycle event you should wait some time before checking if the device is still offline.

> When that message becomes available and is processed (by Lambda or another service), you can first check if the device is still offline before taking further action.

The question here is how do i check if the device is still offline?

The suggested infrastructure in the documentation is a IoT Rule subscribed to topic '$aws/events/presence/disconnected/clientId' will create a message on a SQS queue. The SQS queue will delay the message using the `deliveryDelay` attribute, before a lambda function will consume the message. It is in this lambda function that we should check if the device is still offline.

I could simply implement a dynamodb table with a device state and a timestamp which will be updated every time there is a connect or disconnect event without delay. But there must be a smarter way to determine if the device is still offline?

Comment: Hi - Did Thing Indexing solve this issue? I'm exactly trying to implement the same, but I have seen Thing Indexing can take few seconds to be updated, so I might need to increase the SQS delay above 10 seconds most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the answer. Once the disconnect event is fired, you will assume the client is staying offline unless IoT Core sends update for the same client on the topic '$aws/events/presence/connected/clientId'.

Obviously you need to subscribe both topics.

Thing Indexing is a bad idea in most cases if you think about why you need IoT from beginning. It's only good for Amazon but won't give you any value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Thing Indexing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-index.html). It has the option to index the connectivity status of the device (`thingConnectivityIndexingMode`).

Comment: That looks much better i will check it out now thanks!

Comment: It looks good, but it is super expensive. If you are using fleet indexing only for the connectivity state, your idea with the DynamoDB is much cheaper.

Comment: For the pricing consideration fleet index gives me 1 million state changes for 2.25 USD where as Dynamodb will give me 1 million write for 1.25 USD. 

In terms of querying the state I will get 10.000 for 0.05USD using the fleet index and dynamodb will give me 1 million queries for 0.25USD. BUt this is plus the cost of a lambda function executing the code.

So your point is very good - there is a huge difference is price here. Another thing i consider is that you can not configure fleet index using CDK yet.